# Calculating a transformation matrix to place an object on a sphere in glsl

Tags: matrix, graphics, glsl

I'm trying generate some matrices to place trees on a planet on the GPU. The position of each tree is predetermined - based on a biome map and various heightmap data - but this data is GPU resident so I can't do this on the CPU. At the moment I'm instancing using the geometry shader - this will change to traditional instancing if performance is bad, and I'd then compute the model matrices for each tree on a compute shader.

I've got as far as trying to use a modified version of lookAt() but I can't get it working and even if I did, the trees would be perpendicular to the planet instead of standing up. I know I can define a using 3 axis, so the normal of the sphere, a tangent and a bitangent, but given I don't care what direction these tangents and bitangents are in at the moment, what would be a quick way to calculate this matrix in GLSL? Thanks!

```
void drawInstance(vec3 offset)
{
  //Grab the model's position from the model matrix
  vec3 modelPos = vec3(modelMatrix[3][0],modelMatrix[3][1],modelMatrix[3][2]);
  //Add the offset
  modelPos +=offset;

  //Eye = where the new pos is, look in x direction for now, planet is at origin so up is just the modelPos normalized
  mat4 m = lookAt(modelPos, modelPos + vec3(1,0,0), normalize(modelPos));

  //Lookat is intended as a camera matrix, fix this
  m = inverse(m);

  vec3 pos = gl_in[0].gl_Position.xyz;
  gl_Position = vp * m *vec4(pos, 1.0);
  EmitVertex();

  pos = gl_in[1].gl_Position.xyz ;
  gl_Position = vp * m *vec4(pos, 1.0);
  EmitVertex();

  pos = gl_in[2].gl_Position.xyz;
  gl_Position = vp * m * vec4(pos, 1.0);
  EmitVertex();

  EndPrimitive();
}

void main()
{   
  vp = proj * view;
  mvp = proj * view * modelMatrix;

  drawInstance(vec3(0,20,0));
  // drawInstance(vec3(0,20,0));
  // drawInstance(vec3(0,20,-40));
  // drawInstance(vec3(40,40,0));
  // drawInstance(vec3(-40,0,0));

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution to the problem which allows me to place objects on the surface of a sphere facing in the correct directions. Here is the code:

```
  mat4 m = mat4(1);

  vec3 worldPos = getWorldPoint(sphericalCoords);


  //Add a random number to the world pos, then normalize it so that it is a point on a unit sphere slightly different to the world pos. The vector between them is a tangent. Change this value to rotate the object once placed on the sphere
  vec3 xAxis = normalize(normalize(worldPos + vec3(0.0,0.2,0.0)) - normalize(worldPos));

  //Planet is at 0,0,0 so world pos can be used as the normal, and therefore the y axis
  vec3 yAxis = normalize(worldPos);

  //We can cross the y and x axis to generate a bitangent to use as the z axis
  vec3 zAxis = normalize(cross(yAxis, xAxis));

  //This is our rotation matrix!
  mat3 baseMat = mat3(xAxis, yAxis, zAxis);

  //Fill this into our 4x4 matrix
  m = mat4(baseMat);

  //Transform m by the Radius in the y axis to put it on the surface
  mat4 m2 = transformMatrix(mat4(1), vec3(0,radius,0));
  m = m  * m2;

  //Multiply by the MVP to project correctly
  m = mvp* m;

  //Draw an instance of your object
  drawInstance(m);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend taking a different approach completely.

First, don't use geometry shaders for replicating geometry. That's what the `glDrawArraysInstanced` is for.

Second, it's hard to define such a matrix procedurally. This is related to the [Hairy Ball Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem).

Instead I would generate a bunch of random rotations on the CPU. Use [this method](http://planning.cs.uiuc.edu/node198.html) to create a uniformly distributed quaternion. Pass that quaternion to the vertex shader as a single `vec4` instanced attribute. In the vertex shader:

1. Offset the tree vertex by `(0, 0, radiusOfThePlanet)` so that it's located at the north pole (assuming Z-axis is up).
2. Apply the quaternion rotation (it will rotate around planet center so the tree stays on the surface).
3. Apply the planet model-view and camera projection matrices as usual.

This will yield an unbiased uniformly distributed random set of trees.

Comment: Hi! There is a reason I'm doing this on the GPU rather than traditional instancing; my heightmap data is GPU only, therefore computing correct positions isn't possible on the CPU. If the geometry shader is much worse performing than traditional instancing my plan was to fill out the instancing buffer on a compute shader anyway, so I'd still need the answer to this question

Comment: @Figwig: in the method described you can sample `radiusOfThePlanet` on the GPU in the vertex shader. It does not preclude traditional instancing. CPU calculates only the random rotations.

Comment: I also can't just settle for random positions - their positions are determined by the biome map which is also GPU resident data - so I can't access this from CPU. It's purely the correct model matrix that I need to be able to work out :)

Comment: Without the restrictions I have since mentioned though, this is a great solution. I'll add these details to the original answer